# Titan: fetch sorted result

Tags: titan

Take the scenario of SO,

1. when we click `Questions` button it shows all question regardless of tag,
2. when we click a `tag` it only shows question asked to that particular tag.

Second is ok, I will just go to that particular Tag vertex and fetch the sorted data based on attached edge.

How will i implement the first scenario in sorted order.? I will have java question, html question, c++ question vertex... so and so. How will I fetch all these in sorted order? What will be the query?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you are trying to avoid iterating/sorting all vertices to find recent questions.  One way might be to build some sort of date structure into your schema like:

```
year --> month --> day --> question
```

If you have a sufficient number of "questions" in your you use case you might consider breaking time down further to hours, minutes, etc (or a higher level of aggregation....maybe you just need year and month). Index the edges between the year, month, day, and question using a reverse sort order of the time, so that you can just do:

```
g.V('year','2014').out.out.out[0..<10]
```

which would return the first 10 most recent questions.  Note that Gremlin nicely compiles this to a vertex query to take advantage of your index:

```
gremlin> g.V.has('year','2014').out.out.out[0..<10].toString()
==>[GremlinStartPipe, GraphQueryPipe(has,vertex), IdentityPipe, VertexQueryPipe(out,[],vertex), VertexQueryPipe(out,[],vertex), VertexQueryPipe(out,[],range:[0,9],vertex), IdentityPipe]
```

Comment: I think the question is, how to structure tags and questions without tagging vertices. What's the point of using an extra structure for dates and not only UNIX timestamps?

Comment: I interpreted the question as one being how to retrieve the most recent question vertices in the graph (with the mention of "tags" being incidental to the post).  Perhaps I misinterpreted...I'll let @Manish clarify as to whether or not I've understood.  I'm not sure I follow your question though on "extra structure for dates and not only UNIX timestamps".  Do you just mean, why not just rely on a timestamp property on the question vertex to find most recent questions?  If you can elaborate for me, I can try to answer.

Comment: what i understood is to make `year` `month` `day` vertex then connect `question` vertex to `day`. index all these `day --> question` edge in sorted order. and then traverse from `year` to `month` to `day` to get the result.right?

Comment: yes, @Manish that's what I was suggesting as a way to get around your problem.  The downside is the added "date" structure, but it seems you need a way to start your traversal that then allows use of vertex centric indices.  Perhaps that will inspire you to a solution.